# Worst-case expected running time for Randomized Permutation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis, probability-theory

I have an algorithm which, when given a positive integer N, generates a permutation of the first N integers (from 1 to N) using a method called randInt(x,y). The method randInt(x,y) will generate a random integer between the numbers x and y, provided they are positive integers and y >= x.

The algorithm is given by the following pseudo-code:

```
1.  if (N <= 0) {
2.     return null
3.  } else {
4.     A := new int[] w/ size N and all cells initialized to 0
5.     a[0] := randInt(1,N)
6.     for (i := 1 to length(A)-1) do 
7.        boolean rInA := True
8.        while (rInA) {
9.           rInA := False 
10.          int r := randInt(1,N)
11.          for (j := 0 to (i-1)) do 
12.             if (r = A[j]) {
13.                rInA := True
14.             }
15.          }   
16.       }
17.       A[i] := r
18.    }
19. }
20. return A
```

My understanding of the algorithm is as follows:

The outermost for-loop will run N-1 times and for each of those iterations a random number is generated and then compared to all the previous cells of A that have been visited in previous iterations. If any of the those cells contain that randomly generated number then that number cannot be used and a new number is randomly generated (in the next iteration of that nested while-loop). This new randomly generated number is then, like before, compared to all the previously visited cells in A to check for duplication. This continues until randInt(x,y) generates a random number that is not already in the first i cells of A.

This leads me to believe that the Worst-case expected running time of the algorithm is something like:
$\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}(\alpha i)$

Now the $\alpha$ here represents the effect the while-loop has on the running time and is the point of uncertainty for me. I know that in the first iteration of the outermost for loop its unlikely that randInt will generate the one integer that A already contains (1/N I believe) so that inner-most for-loop is likely to only execute once. However, by the last iteration (of outer-most for-loop) the probability that randInt generates one of the N-1 integers already in A is $\frac{N-1}{N}$ so because of the while-loop its likely that the inner-most for-loop for **that** iteration (of the outer-most for-loop) will execute more like n times.

How can I use the probability introduced into the algorithm by randInt to calculate the algorithms run-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would revise the inner for loop so that checking whether $r$ has been used already, is $O(1)$. As stated, it is $O(n)$.  You could do this by initializing a (1-indexed) boolean array $used[\cdot]$ of length $n$, and setting $used[x]$ equals true whenever you set some $A[i]=x$.

Now the question is how many times may $rand()$ be called in the worst case. Actually, the way the algorithm is set up right now, the *worst* case is $+\infty$; this is because it's not learning from any of its bad choices of $r$. For instance, if it selects $5$, when $5$ was already in $A$, then the smart thing to do would be never to guess $5$ again. There are ways to achieve this; so if you had some method that never repeated guesses, then you can get $O(n^2)$ worst case runtime.

If you are interested in *expected* runtime, then you can calculate the expected number of times $r$ is recalculated in any given step: at step $i$, there are $n-i$ good choices, for a success probability of $\frac{n-i}{n}$. The [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Properties) for number of tries to get a first success in a bernoulli variable with probability $p$, is $\frac{1}{p}$. Then if you sum $\frac{n}{n}+\frac{n}{n-1}+\frac{n}{n-2}+\cdots \frac{n}{1}$ you have asymptotic $O(n\log n)$.  This is basically the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: Thank you for the response! Yes I have two other algorithms that solve the same computational problem much more efficiently, one is exactly how you initially described (utilizing a used array to learn from its mistakes). Another algorithm simply starts with an array of size N initialized to the first N integers in order, it then uses the randInt() method to simply shuffle the numbers already present in the array, thereby only making one pass through the array for its entire execution. I know this algorithm stated in the question is horribly inefficient, but I am forced to work with it.